# Discord.py default role permissions

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

how do i check which permissions the default role in a specific channel has?

I've tried:

```
if member.default_role.permission_in(channel).send_message:
```

but it doesn't work without an error message.
Everything else I tried didn't work either.

Here's my code:

```
@commands.command()
async def unmute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.kick_members:
        for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
            role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="@everyone")
            if role.permission_in(channel).send_message and member.permissions_in(channel).read_messages:
                    await channel.set_permissions(member, send_messages=True)
```

Comment: which event reference are you using?
It would be helpfull If you added more code so we can understand what else is happening

Comment: I don't use an event, the member is defined beforehand

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="@everyone")
    if role is not None:
        perms = role.permissions
        print(perms)
```

Using this it prints the role permissions integer. You can find out what the permissions are by using a permissions calulator

Comment: that doesn't answer my question, i want the bot to check in each channel whether the default role has permissions to read

Comment: instead of perms variable do `if role.permissions.read_messages is True:` its right in the api reference